# Get Discord Token Using Login Info?

Tags: authentication, discord, token, user-accounts

Okay so, I'm trying to build an app that requires the user's token. It's a really time-wasting process for the user to get the token, so here's what I wanna do:

The user enters their login info, & using that info I can fetch the user's token. I want this to happen & happen fast.

Tried searching it but looks like it hasn't been done before. Any Ideas?

P.S Thanks In Advance :D